# The type or namespace name 'Keyless' could not be found ef

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I am using .Net Core 3, with ef model first approach. I want to create a class with no Primary Key, so I have use this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Beyond.Models
{

    public class Bab
    {
       [Keyless]
       public DateTime DateTime { get; }
       }
}
```

But I have this error:

**Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Keyless' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Why this error if I am declaring Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore? How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Keyless annotation was added in EFCore 5.0 so if using a version of EFCore before 5.0 it will give assembly not found compile error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

I believe the Keyless annotation must also be on the class rather than on the field.